# Get title, nav_title and subtitle

Tags: title, typo3, typoscript, subtitle

I want to print the fields `title`, `nav_title` and `subtitle` with Typoscript. I saw that there are several possibilities. E.g. `data`, `field`, `levelfield`, `leveltitle`, ...

Currently I'm using this code (because the only one which works for me so far):

```
lib.heading = TEXT
lib.heading.dataWrap = <p class="title"> {leveltitle:0} </p>
```

but I want something with alternatives like this

`stdWrap.field = subtitle // nav_title // title`

What is the correct way of retrieving these fields?

Edit:

```
[userFunc = user_isMobile]

page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.value (
    // ...
)

// ...

lib.heading = TEXT
#lib.heading.dataWrap = <p class="title"> {leveltitle:0} </p>

lib.heading {
  field = title 
  wrap = <p class="title"> | </p>
}

lib.subpages = HMENU
lib.subpages {
  // ...
}

[global]
```

The userfunction itself is a function in a php script (user_mobile.php). It makes a user agent detection for mobile devices and returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

`field` will get values from the current data which in your context is the data of the current page.

```
lib.heading = TEXT
lib.heading {
  field = subtitle // nav_title // title
  wrap = <p class="title">|</p>
}
```

`leveltitle`, `leveluid`, `levelmedia`, etc. allow you to retrieve some of the data from other pages in the rootline of the current page.

For more information see `getText` in the **[documentation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/2/)**.

Comment: When I use this code the output is empty `<p class="title"></p>`.

Comment: Try `field = subtitle // title`, that is only 2 fields. Does it make any difference?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference. This code only worked for me when building a menu.

Comment: 1. Check that this code is not inside some other code. 2. Make sure you are not leaving out `|` from `<p class="title">|</p>`.

Comment: It's in a `userFunc` condition, but the condition is fulfilled because with `{leveltitle:0}` I get the results. Also the pipe is in the wrap: `lib.heading = TEXT

lib.heading {
  field = title 
  wrap = <p class="title"> | </p>
}`

Comment: Can you explain that "it's in a userFuns"? The thing is, `leveltitle` and similar are sort of special and are usable in any context. On the other hand for `field` the data change according to the context. If you can, post bigger chunk of TypoScript code to see where you are trying to use this.

Comment: I edited my question, but not really much more information here. Tell me if you need something.

Comment: I don't think the condition can have any effect on this whatsoever but just to be sure, have you tried taking the code out of the condition?

Comment: Now I tried it without the condition - still the same result.

Comment: The last thing that comes to my mind is to use *Template -> Template Analyzer* to check for any possible problem with the code.

Comment: I now used `{page:sub_title}` and it is giving me the information I wanted. But it is not ideal because I often have two times the same headline (this is a design mistake). Though your code still not work and template analyzer didn't show me an error.